# <scripts condition="1=1"><![CDATA[

Tags: html, css, master-pages, sharepoint-2013

I'm looking at a former developer's css file and I'm wondering what this means:

```
<scripts condition="1=1"><![CDATA[
```

It prevents the css from being applied unless I remove it (SharePoint 2013).

Under that line is an opening tag

```
<style scoped>
```

and the tag closes at the end of the css

```
</style>
```

What does that all mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:
"The scoped attribute for the  element allows you to include styles mid-document that targets a specific element and its children. Depending upon how you look at this, it’ll either be a godsend or a curse. Once you’ve reached the end of this article, I hope you can form your own opinion."
http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

Comment: To build on this answer, the `<! [CDATA[` "tag" is commonly used to mark a script. Browsers which can't parse the script will ignore it. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) for more information about character data.

Comment: Just an aside: `scoped` would be great if browsers supported it. Currently, [only Firefox does](http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped).